# Is it safe for multiple threads to set ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: c#

To ignore the ssl certificate errors, I am setting `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in a static method before making a `HttpWebRequest`. I only want this to be done for internal requests and so I am resetting the property to its default value in the `finally` block. But because it is a web application, will there be an issues when multiple threads are modifying the property?

Here is how I am using the property

```
public static String GetResource()
{
    try
    {        
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };        
    }
    catch()
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= delegate { return false; };
    }    
}
```

1. Will this code be threadsafe? The documentation on msdn says that any static members of the type ServicePointManager are threadsafe, but I just wanted to confirm.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkfa48de%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
2. The code in the finally block, is that the correct way to reset it to the default value?

Comment: No, this won't be "thread safe".  The callback can be changed by any other thread at any time.

Comment: BTW, "thread safe" in terms of static members simply means that those members atomically modify static state (if any).  Two threads modifying `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is "thread safe" in that respect.  But, from your application's point of view, this isn't thread safe because one thread's data (*its* `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` value) can be overwritten by another thread--potentially causing code in your thread to malfunction.  There is no way to synchronize access to `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in threads you have no control over.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your response. I see a lot of posts where they suggested this technique, but apparently it doesn't work. I am not sure what is the best way to ignore ssl certificate errors for internal web requests.

Comment: best way is to create certificates that don't cause certificate errors.  Otherwise, you'll have to risk the thread-safety issues associated with `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

Comment: It's important to remember that it's part of the TLS/SSL standard to check expiry and chains--that's kind of the purpose of TLS/SSL.  If you want to *ignore* those types of errors, maybe TLS/SSL isn't really the technology you should be using...

Answer (score 6):

If you need to override default certificate validation, consider one or more of the following:

1. Set `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` once and only once -- during application start up or possibly in a static constructor. This eliminates the risk of thread contention.
2. Since you're making security more permissive, limit the behavior to debug builds with conditional compilation:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += Callback;
   #endif
   ```
3. Finally, remember that your delegate is a rich function. You don't have to simply return `true`. You can interrogate the request and decide how to handle it.

   ```
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += Callback;

   static bool Callback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   {
       if (IsInternalRequest(sender))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return IsExternalRequestValid(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
       }
   }
   ```